# Pygame collidepoint() dont account for the blit()

Tags: python, pygame, grid, collision, blit

Sorry for any gramatical mistakes as i'm a non english speaker

I'm working on a small game during this quarantine and wanted to make a map maker in order to speed up the process of designing levels. 
My probleme is that even if the grid show as i expect on the screen, the "getcollide" function does not account for the "blit" of the surface. I spend two days on this and can't think of another way to work this around, here is a sample code :

```
    import pygame

    def run(l, h, fps, scene):
        pygame.init()
        ecran = pygame.display.set_mode((l, h))
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        scene_active = scene

        while scene_active != None:
            key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            filtre_touche = []

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                close = False
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    close = True
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    alt = key[pygame.K_LALT] or touche_active[pygame.K_RALT]
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        close = True
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_F4 and alt:
                        close = True
                if close :
                    scene.quit()
                else :
                    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    filtre_touche.append(event)

            scene_active.traite_input(filtre_touche, key, mouse_pos)
            scene_active.update()
            scene_active.render(ecran)

            scene_active = scene_active.next

            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick(fps)

    surface = pygame.Surface((320,320))
    M = []
    for i in range(10):
        x = []
        for j in range(10):
            x.append(pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255,255,255),(i*32, j*32, 32,32), 1))
        M.append(x)
    print(M)

    class FirstScreen():
        def __init__(self):
            self.next = self
        def traite_input(self, evenement, touche, mouse_pos):
            for event in evenement :
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    pygame.quit()
            for line in M :
                for row in line:
                    if row.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                        print('collide')

        def update (self):
            pass
        def render(self, ecran):
            ecran.fill((200,200,200))
            ecran.blit(surface, (350,250), surface.get_rect())

    run(800,600,60, FirstScreen())
```

If you run this, you will see that the surface is where we expect it to be and the tile actually are of 32 by 32. But hoovering the mouse over the grid has no effect. The print statement is called when you hoover the mouse where the grid should be if i've blit the surface at 0,0.

Am I missing something ? After searching this website, the pygame doc and all kind of forums i seems to be the only one with this trouble, what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Its because your putting the grid on a surface, the bliting the surface on the screen, so when you make the grid, you start at 0 of the surface. Then blit the surface in the middle(ish) of the screen, when you do the `collidepoint`. the mouse hovers over it when near 0, the top left of the whole screen. Basically, the position of the mouse on the window is translated to the surface so when you hover the mouse over the grid, the pos of the mouse in the window is not on the grid on the surface. if that makes sense.

Easy fix:

```
if row.collidepoint((mouse_pos[0] - 350,mouse_pos[1] - 250)):
```

move the mouse pos back so 0,0 on the surface is 0,0 on the window

Comment: Thanks for your answer !  :)

So a rect drawn on a surface not 'following' the surface after a blit is normal behavior ? I find this kinda weird, but at least I understand why I wasn't able to find my mistakes. Thanks !

Surfaces seems a lot less useful now that you've enlight me 

So, in my case of a map maker, if I want to make button to 'choose kind of tile' to to the left of my screen and a grid in the middle to put the tiles on, i'll have to manually convert all coordinates from screen to surfaces and potentially breack the button actually at 0,0 ?

Comment: Edit : I've understood that I'm not 'breaking' the 0,0 button by moving the mouse pos back, since I'm looking for collision only in these particular row. 
But did you know if there is a way to know all the 'child' of a surface to apply modification to all of them at once and not 'hard code' zoom in/zoom out/position editing ?

Comment: Don't entirely understand, but, instead of making the grid on a surface, then bliting the surface onto the screen, just make the grid on the screen, that would be the easiest way. then you don't have to worry about converting mouse pos. As the screen is a surface

Comment: And, rect drawn on surface not following surface, think of it like drawing a picture in photoshop, then putting that picture in another picture, its position stays the same in the first picture(local), but in the 2nd picture, its changed(global)

Comment: I'm drawing on a surface in order to make a 20*20 grid on a 10*10 surfaces and not showing the whole grid but make it 'scrolable' inside the surfaces. It should be possible with your trick of subtracting the blit to the mouse pos, thanks again :)

For the base interface I'm now gonna work directly with the screen yes, it will save me some time with buttons settings

Thanks, I now understand with the Photoshop example, I should be able to make a small function who convert back the 'mouse pos' in 'local mouse pos' with the 'surface.get_rect()'. 

Thanks again for your time and quick answer